# Which predictors are most important based on lasso plot?

Tags: matlab, regularization, importance

I apologize in advance if this question is silly.
I'm trying to identify which predictors are most important and what the right lambda value to choose based on the lasso plot in Matlab.

Here is my code:

```
     z=zscore([Age Height Weight]);
     x=[ z dv_gender(:,1 ) Smoker dv_loc(:,[1 2])    
     dv_selfassed(:,[1 2 3])]; 
     y= Systolic;
     ml=fitlm(x,y)
     [b fitinfo] = lasso(x, y, 'CV',10, 'Alpha', 1);
     lassoPlot(b,fitinfo,'PlotType', 'Lambda', 'XScale', 'log');
```

[image: here is the result]

- I think  B5 the light green and B3 are the most important variables do you think so ?.
- and the lambda should be in place between the dotted lines but I don't know how I get it value. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Could you explain--preferably quantitatively--what you mean by "important"?

Comment: I mean which variables have a high impact on Systolic.